# How do I get the "visible" length of a combining Unicode string in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

If I have a Python Unicode string that contains combining characters, `len` reports a value that does not correspond to the number of characters "seen".

For example, if I have a string with combining overlines and underlines such as `u'A\u0332\u0305BC'`, `len(u'A\u0332\u0305BC')` reports 5; but the displayed string is only 3 characters long.

How do I get the "visible" — that is, number of distinct positions occupied by the string the user sees — length of a Unicode string containing combining glyphs in Python?

Comment: hmm this is interesting, the best I can think of is just stripping the unwanted chars.

Comment: @riotburn: That will be difficult. The characters could be arbitrary (user-supplied). I'd need to consult a list of what Unicode glyphs are combining — unless that's a systematic part of the encoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`unicodedata` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html) has a function `combining` that can be used to determine if a single character is a combining character. If it returns `0` you can count the character as non-combining.

```
import unicodedata
len(u''.join(ch for ch in u'A\u0332\u0305BC' if unicodedata.combining(ch) == 0))
```

or, slightly simpler:

```
sum(1 for ch in u'A\u0332\u0305BC' if unicodedata.combining(ch) == 0)
```

---

Edit: as pointed out in the comments, there are code points other than combining marks that modify a character without being a character themselves that should not be in the count.  Here's a more robust version of the above:

```
modifier_categories = set(['Mc', 'Mn'])
sum(1 for ch in u'A\u0332\u0305BC' if unicodedata.category(ch) not in modifier_categories)
```

We can use another Python trick to make that even simpler, taking advantage of `True==1` and `False==0`:

```
sum(unicodedata.category(ch) not in modifier_categories for ch in u'A\u0332\u0305BC')
```

Comment: Or: `sum(not unicodedata.combining(ch) for ch in u'A\u0332\u0305BC')`.

Comment: @Bakuriu at first I thought that wouldn't work since `combining` returns integers that aren't `0` or `1`, but `not` takes care of that. Well done!

Comment: This doesn't work for grapheme clusters made from non-marking characters, for example: `u'\u1100\u1161\u11A8'` (각).

Comment: @一二三 is there something else in `unicodedata` that would handle that case?

Comment: No, `unicodedata` is insufficient for solving this problem as it doesn't expose the "Grapheme_Cluster_Break" property. Libraries like `PyICU` do, but the answer by @dawg is probably the simplest way to get at it.

Comment: BTW `0` is falsy, so you could use `not` instead of `== 0`, like this `len(u''.join(ch for ch in u'A\u0332\u0305BC' if not unicodedata.combining(ch)))`

Comment: unicodedata.combining() also doesn't work with [variation sequences](https://www.unicode.org/faq/vs.html). For example, both "\u25b6" and "\u25b6\uFE0F" display as single characters but the latter claims length 2 by all the above snippets.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a regex flavor that supports matching [grapheme](http://unicode.org/glossary/#grapheme), you can use `\X`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lG7iD9/1)

While the default Python re module does not support `\X`, Matthew Barnett's [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) does:

```
>>> len(regex.findall(r'\X', u'A\u0332\u0305BC'))
3
```

On Python 2, you need to use `u` in the pattern:

```
>>> regex.findall(u'\\X', u'A\u0332\u0305BC')
[u'A\u0332\u0305', u'B', u'C']
>>> len(regex.findall(u'\\X', u'A\u0332\u0305BC'))
3
```

Answer (score 3):

Combining characters are not the only zero-width characters:

```
>>> sum(1 for ch in u'\u200c' if unicodedata.combining(ch) == 0)
1
```

(`"\u200c"` or `"‌"` is zero-width non-joiner; it's a non-printing character.)

In this case the regex module does not work either:

```
>>> len(regex.findall(r'\X', u'\u200c'))
1
```

I found [wcwidth](https://github.com/jquast/wcwidth) that handles the above case correctly:

```
>>> from wcwidth import wcswidth
>>> wcswidth(u'A\u0332\u0305BC')
3
>>> wcswidth(u'\u200c')
0
```

But still doesn't seem to work with user 596219's example:

```
>>> wcswidth('각')
4
```

Comment: The regex module has some updates about zero-width matches in Python 3.7, so maybe it will work properly now. I haven't tried it myself.