# How can I get sensible results from len(), str.format() and a zero-width space?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, formatting, zero-width-space

I'm trying to format text in a kind of table and write the result to a file, but I have problems with the alignment, because my source sometimes contains the Unicode character 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' or `\u200b` in python.
Consider the following code example:

```
str_list = ("a\u200b\u200b", "b", "longest entry\u200b")
format_str = "|{string:<{width}}| output of len(): {length}\n"

max_width = 0
for item in str_list:
    if len(item) > max_width:
        max_width = len(item)

with open("tmp", mode='w', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for item in str_list:
        file.write(format_str.format(string=item,
                                     width=max_width,
                                     length=len(item)))
```

Content of 'tmp' after running above script:

```
|a​​           | output of len(): 3
|b             | output of len(): 1
|longest entry​| output of len(): 14
```

So this looks like `len()` does not result in the 'printed width' of the string, and `str.format()` does not know how to handle zero width characters.

Or, this behavior is intentional and I need to do something else.

To be clear, I'm looking for a way to get something like this result:

```
|a​​            | output of len(): 1
|b            | output of len(): 1
|longest entry​| output of len(): 13
```

I'd prefer if it's possible to do without mangling my source.

Comment: _"this looks like len() does not result in the 'printed width' of the string"_. Yes, I believe this is intended behavior. [How do I get the “visible” length of a combining Unicode string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33351599/953482) may be of interest to you.

Comment: The width of the zero width space character depends on the font. You can use a font where it non-printing spaces display as a regular space. Or you can change the string `item = item.replace('\u200b', ' ')`

Comment: @Kevin The accepted answer from your link does not work here. The reported length for the strings match the result of len()

Comment: @rhall, yeah, I thought that might be the case, since I don't think `ZERO WIDTH SPACE` is a "combining character". What's your opinion on the `wcwidth` project mentioned in the third post?

Comment: @HåkenLid Ok, so i'm not using a font where non-printing characters are printed and i assume that it is the intended way of 'displaying' non-printables. I'm trying to avoid replacing/regex solutions since there might be more characters i have to look for. See [zero width unicode chars](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=zero+width&han=Y&preview=entity), and i don't know how many more exist?

Comment: @Kevin That looks promising, thanks for pointing that out. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [wcwidth](https://github.com/jquast/wcwidth) package has a function `wcswidth()` which returns the width of a string in character cells:

```
from wcwidth import wcswidth

length = len('sneaky\u200bPete')      # 11
width = wcswidth('sneaky\u200bPete')  # 10
```

The difference between `wcswidth(s)` and `len(s)` can then be used to correct for the error introduced by `str.format()`. Modifying your code above:

```
from wcwidth import wcswidth

str_list = ("a\u200b\u200b", "b", "longest entry\u200b")
format_str = "|{s:<{fmt_width}}| width: {width}, error: {fmt_error}\n"

max_width = max(wcswidth(s) for s in str_list)

with open("tmp", mode='w', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for s in str_list:
        width = wcswidth(s)
        fmt_error = len(s) - width
        fmt_width = max_width + fmt_error
        file.write(format_str.format(s=s,
                                     fmt_width=fmt_width,
                                     width=width,
                                     fmt_error=fmt_error))
```

… produces this output:

```
|a​​            | width: 1, error: 2
|b            | width: 1, error: 0
|longest entry​| width: 13, error: 1
```

It also produces correct output for strings including double-width characters:

```
str_list = ("a\u200b\u200b", "b", "㓵", "longest entry\u200b")
```

```
|a​​            | width: 1, error: 2
|b            | width: 1, error: 0
|㓵           | width: 2, error: -1
|longest entry​| width: 13, error: 1
```

Comment: Running `wcwidth.wcwidth` on a zero-width non-breaking space (U+FEFF) is giving 1 when it should be 0 (see [issue](https://github.com/jquast/wcwidth/issues/22)), so in my code I had to add a special case to set its width to 0.